# How to make all textfields close keyboard on return?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am currently learning Swift and have some TextFields in my application. Now I want the user to close the keyboard if he presses the return key in a TextField or taps anywhere on the screen.

Currently I add the same code in all of my controllers which I do not really like. Is there a way to make all controllers / TextFields to behave the way I described above.

Closing the keyboard with return:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Closing the keyboard on tapping on the screen:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This I want to have in all of my Controllers without copying it each time.

Comment: Consider using a Class Extension on UIViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass the `UITextField` and create your own TextField. Than if you add a `UITextField` to your Storyboard, just set the class to your textfield class in the identity inspector.

```
class YourTextField : UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do the same with UIViewController and add the touchesBegan method to it? Sry, I am quite new to Swift.

Comment: Yes you can do that. If you think about it, you do the exact same thing if you create a UIViewController class. You just edit it like you want to.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks. Gonna mark as correct as soon as I get it working!

Comment: @Deutro I've written it without Xcode. If something doesn't work, let me know it or use the auto completion xcode provides.

Comment: Ayyy, this works like a charm! Is there a way to always add a TextField with the custom class or do I have to set it each time I add a TextField?

Comment: You have to set your class each time you add a new textfield.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72698/discussion-between-deutro-and-christian).